# Dynamically delete multiple foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

No Idea how this happened, but we have multiple of the same FK constraint on the same Column. I think they were named by some management studio type thing, meaning they aren't a default constraint, and they aren't named by a human.

I have this query to find the constraint names

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Device' 
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%Address%';
```

How can I drop each constraint in the result set? I guess I'd have to iterate through and do a drop constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
Declare @Query Nvarchar(Max)
Declare @name Nvarchar(150)

Declare Cur Cursor For

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Device' 
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%Address%';

Open Cur

Fetch Next From Cur
Into @name

While @@fetch_status=0
Begin

    Set @Query='Alter table Device 
    DROP CONSTRAINT '+Ltrim(Rtrim(@name))

    Execute sp_executesql @Query

    Fetch Next From Cur
    Into @name
End
Close Cur
Deallocate Cur

Go
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can imagine doing it is like you said, iterate through each time and drop it using a cursor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) or writing dynamic SQL.

Comment: Just tried a cursor. I get a syntax error when I try to use the variable name as the foreign key ID

Comment: MelgoV showed how to alleviate the issue in my above comment, pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need a cursor or any kind of looping for this. Just use sql to build your sql statements. Run the below query to generate your sql. Then just copy and paste into a new tab. Voila! This approach even allows you skip dropping some if you want.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ';'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Device' 
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%Address%';
```

If you totally want to automate it you could use a variable to hold the results and execute it.

Comment: so it can be improved by just using dynamic sql with `exec()`